# Typescript intersection type T is not assignable to type T&U

Tags: typescript

As it is explained in the  [typescript handbook](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/unions-and-intersections.html#intersection-types)

> An intersection type combines multiple types into one. This allows you to add together existing types to get a single type that has all the features you need.

here is a extend function

```
function extend<T extends object, U extends object>(first: T, second: U): T & U {
  const result = <T & U>{};
  for (let id in first) {
    (<T>result)[id] = first[id];
  }
  for (let id in second) {
    if (!result.hasOwnProperty(id)) {
      (<U>result)[id] = second[id];
    }
  }

  return result;
}

const x = extend({ a: 'hello' }, { b: 42 });
```

The variable `result` is asserted as type `T&U` . so it should have **both** properties on type `U` and type `T`, right?

when we iterate the properties on type T , why `result` is asserted as type `T`

```
  for (let id in first) {
    // I'm confused about code below 
    (<T>result)[id] = first[id];
  }
```

I thought there is no need to asset `result` as type T , but I got **error**

```
  for (let id in first) {
    result[id] = first[id];
    // error
    //Type 'T[Extract<keyof T, string>]' is not assignable to type '(T & U)[Extract<keyof T, string>]'.
    //Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'T & U'.
    // Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'T & U'.
    // Type 'object' is not assignable to type 'T'.
    // 'object' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a 
    //  different subtype of constraint 'object'.
  }
```

could anyone explain the error and give a more specific code example when the error would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is when your two types `T` and `U` share a property name with different types. Consider this case:

```
interface Button { state: 'OFF' | 'ON' }
interface Dial { state: 'OFF' | 1 | 2 | 3 }

let button = { state: 'ON' };
let dial = { state: 3 };

let obj = {} as Button & Dial;

// this property has type 'OFF', otherwise it can't be both a Button and a Dial
obj.state

// this is a type error because button.state isn't necessarily a valid Dial state
obj.state = button.state;
// this is a type error because dial.state isn't necessarily a valid Button state
obj.state = dial.state;
```

This isn't a technicality; in general your function is not type-safe, because it doesn't always return something that is both a valid `T` and a valid `U`. The compiler is correct to give an error here. A type assertion should only be used to silence the error if you know that the function will only ever be called with types whose shared properties are consistent (or which have no shared properties).

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIFcxgPYmQb2QGcw5IAuZAcgHkAxOq5AH2poDkmBfAKFEliIUAEWBwANgWKkKbBk1YBGFsgBMKgMzJePcRDDIARphx4AvFJJkIlWp20BuXfuQATMZIuErsrVyfOBtiGAFbIXlzIcERoJrjIAGTIohIBAPRpyGAAFsAxAA5Q2PnQYACeyNnRWWUlcowANMjYOdAA7nkowAYIcCBUBoYohi3ZUbFY8X2u4yniPMEhAHQ+EDw8GVm5MXnj5XXQRVBGEL3oRMNxICsyXUT9BiCnEEREcFDA4hVwyABuEsAZnNpNYFqEbtZwkYrhDIE5NjldrsfvsUIdsMchmcLm4PLC7g9kE8kK93p9vn8ATMMJM8KswctVlD3BJ8U4gA)